# Navigation Dropdown Text Color doesn't work in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, multiple-browsers

I was able to get the navigation dropdown to show the letters in a different color from the background (white in this case) in Chrome browser.  But when I view the same page in IE or FF, the whole background is just all green.

Here is an example of such a page:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hikes_and_groups.php

And here is the CSS code that makes the color show up white in Chrome

```
#navigation li li a {
    color: #white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

To see the difference, just mouse over the top right where it says "community" or "hikes"

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take out the hash symbol from color: #white. "white" is a keyword, the hash signifies it's a color coded in hexadecimal, such as #fff.

```
#navigation li li a {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: You know that fixed the FF issue, but it is still problematic in IE.  Any ideas why that might be?